# Is it possible to retrieve mongo db instance through jndi?

Tags: mongodb, tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

I am trying to get the instance of mongo db through jndi but i am getting exception.For this I am following like this ,first I have added mongo java driver under tomcat/lib.In code to retrieve the instance of mongo I use the following code snippet.

```
@Bean
public MongoDatabase dataSource() throws NamingException {

    System.out.println("Datasource Configuration.........");
    Context intialContext = new InitialContext();

    return (MongoDatabase) intialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/testMongodbDS");

}// dataSource()
```

In server.xml of tomcat I have added resource tag under GlobalNamingResource as follows.

```
<Resource auth="Container" connectionPoolName="newDb" driverClassName="com.mongodb.MongoClient" global="jdbc/testMongodbDS" maxActive="100" maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000" minIdle="5" name="jdbc/testMongodbDS"  url="jdbc:mongodb:Server=MyServer;Port=27017;Database=testmongo;User=;Password=;"validateConnectionOnBorrow="true"/>
```

In gradle for mongo java driver I have used following dependency

```
compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver'
```

Thanks in advance for suggestion guys.